# PyRhO seems to have broken my other libraries upon installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 and Python 3.6, and have been using this laptop and common Python libraries (numpy, scipy, matplotlib) without any issue for several months now. I used

```
pip3 install pyrho
```

to install the [PyRhO module](https://pypi.org/project/PyRhO/) for some specific needs I had. It installed without issue, then without changing anything in my code, I ran it like I always do:

```
python3 [filename].py
```

This gave me an error I'd never seen before:

```
python3 chiral_tensor.py Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chiral_tensor.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/chris/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/chris/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/home/chris/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "/home/chris/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods
  File "/home/chris/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

I've tried looking at the ndarray object's attributes and Googling the error, but I haven't found anything. When I comment out the

```
import numpy
```

line, I just get the same exact error for scipy, then for matplotlib if I comment out the scipy line.

I've since tried uninstalling PyRhO, which didn't change anything. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy, but that hasn't fixed it either.

I'm still relatively new to Linux, so maybe I did something I shouldn't have, but if I did, I'm not seeing it. If anyone has any advice, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the installation suggested by the [documentation](https://github.com/ProjectPyRhO/PyRhO):

```
pip install pyrho[full]
```

rather than just

```
pip install pyrho
```

Comment: The installation went through without issue, but the same error with importing numpy I discussed in my post is still happening when I try to run my code.

Comment: Maybe try `pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed`.

Comment: Actually it looks like this might be a bug in the latest numpy release: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12736 .. Check the thread for workarounds.

Comment: The thread you linked seems to be the exact problem I'm having. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: It worked! I posted an answer as a response to my original post with a detailed explanation of what I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to AidanGawronski, the problem was fixed. I went to [a Github page for the error](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12736) and for me, it turned out that I had multiple redundant instances of numpy installed, so I just kept using

```
sudo pip3 uninstall numpy
```

then

```
pip3 list
```

to uninstall and check if I had finally uninstalled all instances of numpy. Once I had gotten rid of all of them, I used

```
sudo -E pip3 install --upgrade numpy
```

and it fixed the issue.